# How to get days since the beginning of the month (including today) in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a possibility to calculate and display days since the beginning of current month? For example, today is 13.10 so I would like to display all days from 1.10 till 13.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you asked for:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
td = date.today()
dates = [(td - timedelta(i)).strftime('%d.%m.') for i in range(td.day)[::-1]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works great

Answer (score 3):

You can use `date` to get today's day, and then extract the range form the beginning of the month:

```
from datetime import date
days = range(1, date.today().day)
```

Comment: Think you need a `+1` there...

Comment: thank you but this code displays numbers ( from 1 to 12 in this case ) So I have to add 1 to date.today().day, but then ,in the event that month has 30 days the tool returns 31 and it is a problem ( correct me if i am wrong )